# Parsing Multiple .XML Files For Node Values

Tags: xml, powershell

Attempting to read multiple xml files and gather the values for multiple nodes.

$configlist is a txt file containing multiple xml files in a UNC Path

```
\\server\path\to\cml.config
\\otherserver\path\to\xml.config
```

If I try one of the UNC paths as a one off, outside of the foreach (ie [xml]$xmlfull = (Get-Content "\uncpath\to\xml.config"), it works, If I try to iterate through the list with a foreach, it does nothing.

How can I get this to work with the multiple XML files from the $configlist?

```
$configlist= (get-content C:\temp\cfgpath_tested.txt)
Foreach ($cfg in $configlist)
{ 
[xml]$xmlfull = (Get-Content "$cfg")
$result = $xmlfull.configuration.location | ForEach-Object {
    $client        = $_.path
    $allowUnlisted = $_.'system.WebServer'.security.ipSecurity.allowUnlisted
    foreach ($item in $_.'system.WebServer'.security.ipSecurity.add) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            ExampleClient = $client 
            AllowUnlisted = $allowUnlisted
            IPAddress     = $item.ipAddress
            SubnetMask    = $item.subnetMask
      } 
    } 
  }
}

# output on screen
$result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the results in the first loop:

```
$result = foreach ($cfg in $configlist)
```

And remove the `$result =` from line `$result =  $xmlfull.configuration.location`

<sup>Sorry, on mobile so a short answer this time..</sup>

Comment: I see you cross-posted this query.  I also provide an answer on the other site you posted this to. Yet, a bit longer explanation vs what Theo gives you here, but both get you your results. Be sure to let folks know you did this on all sites you did it on as a courtesy and follow-up for those who come across the same need.